Deploying strapi with Azure results in unreachable container
I do everything as instructed in this PaaS guide:https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/azure#paas-deployment-guides
My resources:

My WebApp env variables:

Both build and deployment of Github workflow is successful, Azure deployment also. No error logs.
But when I open application URL, this screen is shown after 1.5 minute load time:

Only usefull error log, is from "Web App down" diagnosis tool:

Where should I event start to look for a problem?
I have not created a container, does Azure created a container for me?
App works fine locally
I tried hanging ports, changing re-deploying, different node versions, no of these helped.

Vidmantas add the following command to the startup command in the configuration section of the Azure web app.
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa

@Zilvinas did you ever figure out what caused this issue and how to fix?

I created Strapi using the command below:
npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart

According to this document, I added the line below to the script section of the package.json:
"start": "node node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js start"

Below is complete package.json file.
package.json:
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "node node_modules/@strapi/strapi/bin/strapi.js start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.23.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.23.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.23.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.23.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "8.6.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "id"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

For deployment purposes, I ran the command below:
npm run build

It generates the build folder.
After successfully deploying Strapi to the Azure web app, I also faced the same issue. So, I added this line pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa to the Azure Web app Configuration -> Startup Command, as shown below.

Azure Output :

